# Bash: replacing a substring in pipe stdin

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin

I try to replace a certain substring from the stdin with a new substring. I have to get the stdin from the pipe, after reading several files by `cat`. Then I want to push the changed string forward to the pipe.

Here is what I try to do:

`cat file1 file2 | echo ${#(cat)/@path_to_file/'path//to//file'} | ... | ... | ... | ...`

I try to replace the substring `@path_to_file` with the replacement substring `'path/to/file'` (the surrounding quotes are part of the replacement substring).

However bash gives me an error message: `bad substitution`

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: `sed`? Or did I miss something in your question?

Comment: @rapt: IMHO it is not possible to use `cat` with Parameter Expansion to catch stdin and replace it.

Comment: @Cyrus why would it be different from any other variable? http://mockingeye.com/blog/2013/01/22/reading-everything-stdin-in-a-bash-script/

Comment: `$(cat)` reads everything from stdin and write to stdout. Example: `echo 123 | printf "%0.8d" $(cat)`, printf itself reads not from stdin. `${#(cat)/foo/bar}` is incorrect syntax. Correct but reads not from stdin: `${a/foo/bar}` to replace first foo by bar in $a. See "Parameter Expansion": `man bash`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the command sed.

```
cat file1 file2 | sed -e 's/@path_to_file/path/to/file/' ...
```

Comment: Consider: `'s|@path_to_file|path/to/file|'`

Answer (score 3):

With Parameter Expansion:

```
cat file1 file2 | while read -r line; do echo "${line/@path_to_file/path\/to\/file}"; done
```